# Angular 2 click event is not displaying and not working

Tags: angular2-template

I am trying to put a click event in an anchor tag but the event is not showing in chrome.

below is the html

```
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 paddInner" *ngIf="module.valid">
            <div class="row marLeftRight_0">
                <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
                    <div class="dashboard-icon ">
                        <img src="./assets/img/icon/Merchant_onboarding_03.png" alt="MerchantBoarding" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-8" >
                    <div class="dvIndexInnerHeader">
                        <a  (click)="goTomethod()">ABC</a>
                    </div>
                    <p class="pSections">
                       asasasa
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
```

component.ts

```
 public goTomethod() {
        this.module.goTomethod();
    }
```

[image]